# Hold all API request into mongoDB unitl MicroService is up

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm calling MicroService from mine NodeJS middleware, I want to hold all API request coming from front-End, if Microservice is down to hold them all and try after some time to exec them, example below API want to store to MongoDB.

Current try: I'm trying to save the req to MongoDB but getting the "cyclic dependency detected" error,

Sample try:

```
async apiQueue(req, res){
try{
    let a = {
        apirequest: req,
        description: 'tesing!!!!'
    }

     const api = new apiQueue(a);
     let savedApi = await api.save();

     res.send(savedApi)
    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).send({'error': e.message});
    }
}
```

Any idea how to store the API request, thanks in advance.

Comment: `req` is a dynamic object, encapsulating (amongst other things) an actual network connection between your server and the client. You can't store those in a database and revive them somehow (think about it: how would it recreate the connection between the client and the server?). Instead, take a look at something like [`promise-retry`](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-promise-retry) that you can use to retry API requests.

Comment: Storing whole request object in database is difficult, you will need to serialise the request object in some way before storing it database. If you really want to store it to database then prefer storing only query, path, body parameters and headers which you can use to retry the request. You also have an option to implement queuing / messaging like rabbitMq or kafka etc. to handle inter process communication between your app and microservice.

Comment: @Amolpskamble thanks I thought of doing same and implemented a similar kind of solution.